# SSRS bar chart has column for date that's not in the data

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm creating a bar chart based on the year of the date field.  There is no data with a 2019 date.  The bar chart includes a year column for 2019.  How can I remove this empty column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You will usually see this when the Axis type is set to `Scalar (Numbers/Dates)`.

There are a few ways to fix this but the easiest are...

1. if your year values are simply numbers then you can set the axis type to `Category` via the UI or set the `Scalar` property to `False`
2. If the above is not suitable for you then set the `HideEndLabels` property to `True` (also available via the UI on 'Labels' tab)

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Axis type** to **Category**.

[image: Before]

[image: Change]

[image: After]